# Select Distinct in Generic Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

When writing a generic inquiry in Acumatica, how can I eliminate duplicates (to do the equivalent of what in SQL would be `SELECT DISTINCT`)?

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you already [google `acumatica query`](https://www.google.de/?q=acumatica+query)` or can you point on some docs you are confused with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic inquiries in Acumatica do not support `SELECT DISTINCT` statement, you should compose joins in a manner to ensure there are no duplicates in result grid or use aggregation.

Another option to consider is custom DAC mapped on a SQL view, please see [SQL View to get complex data but for which company](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898838/sql-view-to-get-complex-data-but-for-which-company) thread for example